# subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ which is isomorphic to $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I want to find the subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ which is isomorphic to $S_4$, $4$th symmetry group. First $n=4$,let $A,B\in GL_4(\mathbb{C})$ be 
$$ A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0 \end{array}\right),B=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{array}\right)$$
Then the subgroup of $GL_4(\mathbb{C})$ generated by $A$ and $B$ is isomorphic to $S_4$. Similarly there are subgroups of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ isomorphic to $S_4$ when $n\geq 5$.

My question: Are there subgroups of $GL_3(\mathbb{C})$ and $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ which is isomorphic to $S_4$? Please give me some advice.

Comment: Look at the character table of $S_4$. Are there faithful $3$- or $2$-dimensional characters of $S_4$?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown:There is a 2-dimensional character and two 2-dimensional characters.

Comment: Remember that the 2-dimensional character comes from inflating a character of $S_3$. As $S_4/V_4\simeq S_3$ we have a surjective homomorphism $S_4\to S_3$ and can compose any irreducible rep of $S_3$ with that to get an irreducible rep of $S_4$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I see. But I can't understand what you want to tell yet.  Can I compose a subgroup of $GL_3(\mathbb{C})$ with that of $GL_4(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: What does it mean to "compose" a subgroup of one group with a subgroup of another and what does that have with Jyrki's commment? | Tangential comment: it is a nice exercise to see that the symmetry group of the cube in $\Bbb R^3$ is $S_4$ (with the standard action on the cube's four space diagonals). That puts it in ${\rm GL}_3(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: @anon: I like the tetrahedron inscribed in the cube !.... note however that not all the symmetries of the cube will invariante the tetrahedron, just half of them -- the full group has order $48$.

Comment: @orangeskid Right, namely $A_4$. (Also I should have said ${\rm SO}(3)$ to be more specific in my comment.)

Comment: @masutarou Are these characters **faithful**? A character is faithful if $\chi(e)\ne\chi(g)$ for all $g\ne e$ ($e$ the identity).

Comment: @anon: the subgroup that invariates the tetrahedron is the "other" subgroup of index $2$... I know that baffled me

Comment: @orangeskid Not sure what you mean, $S_4$ only has one subgroup of index $2$. Perhaps you're referring to this $A_4$ (orientation-preserving tetrahedral symmetry) having two distinct but isomorphic overgroups: one $S_4$ of tetrahedral symmetries which include reflections, and a distinct $S_4$ of rotational symmetries of the cube.

Comment: @anon: it's about the group of isometries of the cube. Also, I don't think $S_4$  is the group of rotational symmetries of the cube. If it were, then $S_4$ would have a $3$ dimensional irreducible with matrices of determinant $1$, not possible ( there is only "one" such representation).

Comment: @orangeskid It's a standard fact that the orientation-preserving symmetries of the cube are $S_4$. Compute its order to be $24$ using orbit-stabilizer, observe there is a map $G\to S_4$ since $G$ acts on the four space diagonals, then verify the image hits each cycle type in $S_4$ (fun). | There are two 3D irreps of $S_4$, the standard rep ($\Bbb R^4$ mod $(1,1,1,1)$) and its tensor product with the 1D sign rep. This case must be the latter irrep since half-turns around cube faces (conjugate to ${\rm diag}(1,-1,-1)$) have negative trace, and the standard rep's character is nonnegative-valued.

Comment: @anon: I agree, the argument with the $3$ dim representation is incorrect, there are two of them. But here is why I still don't think we have there $S_4$. Let $G$ be the group of rotations of the cube, of order $24$. The subgroup $H$ hat invariates one tetrahedron $T$ is iso to $A_4$. Consider $\sigma$ in $G$. Then $\sigma H \sigma^{-1}$ will be the subgroup that invariates the tetrahedron $\sigma T$. That may happen to be $T'$, the other one. So $H$ is not normal in $G$, hence $G$ cannot be $S_4$.

Comment: @orangeskid The subgroup $H<G$ that preserves one inscribed tetrahedron also preserves the other one. So $\sigma H\sigma^{-1}=H$ and $H$ is indeed normal.

Comment: @anon: Oh, got it. Thanks, that was very useful!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Sorry for late reply. These characters are not faithful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that your $4\times 4$ permutation matrices invariante a subspace of $\dim 3$ given by $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 0$. Taking a basis of this subspace $e_i - e_{i+1}$, $1\le i \le 3$ gives a subgroup of $GL(3, \mathbb{C})$ ( in fact $GL(3, \mathbb{Z})$) that is isomorphic to $S_4$.

Let's show that there does not exist a subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb{C})$ that is isomorphic to $S_4$. Assume there exists such one, call it $G$. Since $G$ is finite, there exists a positive hermitian form invariant under $G$. Any such form is obtained from the standard one by composing with a map from $GL(2, \mathbb{C})$. Hence, $G$ is contained in a conjugate of $U(2)$. We may assume $G \subset U(2)$. Now, the subgroup 
$$\{ 1, (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(2,3)\}$$ is in $A_4$, the derived subgroup of $S_4$. Therefore, there exists a subgroup $K$ of $[G,G] \subset [U(2),U(2)]$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2$. Now, we have an abelian subgroup included in $SU(2)$. We know that any commuting family of unitary operators is diagonalisable. Therefore, we may assume that $K$ is contained in the subgroup of diagonal matrices of $SU(2)$. But this one is isomorphic to $S^1$. Now, any finite subgroup of $S^1$ is cyclic. But $K$ is not cyclic. Here we have a contradiction.

We have showed in fact that there is no subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb{C})$ (equivalently $SU(2)$) isomorphic to $A_4$. Now, there exists a subgroup of $O(3,\mathbb{R})$  isomorphic to $S_4$ ( the isometries of a tetrahedron), so a subgroup of $SO(3,\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to $A_4$.

We have a cover 
$$1 \to \{ \pm 1\} \to SU(2)\to SO(3,\mathbb{R})\to 1$$
Denote by $\tilde{A}_4$ the preimage of $A_4$. We have a no split cover
$$1 \to \{\pm 1\} \to \tilde{A}_4 \to A_4 \to 1$$
Recall that $SU(2)$ can be seen as the group of quaternions of norm $1$. Then $\tilde{A}_4$ will be the group of [Hurwitz quaternions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_quaternion) of norm $1$. The preimage $\tilde{K}$ of $K$ is $\{\pm 1, \pm i , \pm j, \pm k\}$.

$\bf{Added:}$ Something that appeared in the proof: for a compact group like $U(n)$ or $SU(n)$ any abelian subgroup is contained in a maximal torus, while for $SO(3, \mathbb{R})$ already this is not true ( $K$ ).